# How to copy and paste this formula across cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a spreadsheet and I need two column to calculate the total.

I have to manually insert formula all the way across to multiple cells. Is there an easier way instead of manually inserting these functions one cell at a time?

Comment: What is the format you need? Is it formatting as `currency`, make them **Bold**?

Comment: `I want to copy the formula from one cell and paste it to another cell but I need that formula to automatically change to fit the correct cell . I can't screenshot it . ` Why you can't screenshot it? Then give us a sample of data and formula you needed to copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Format Painter" function from the start ribbon. (Before clicking the button, make sure the cell with the format you want to copy is currently selected)

[image: The button is in the start ribbon]
[image: result]

Comment: I did that but I need the format to change to meet the correct cell. for example im using C 24-38 for the rates and I need them to calculate with cell D. if I did the formula for =e5*$c5 and i copy and paste that into cell D, it will not change to =d5*$c5.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm having difficulties trying to understand what you want to do. Do you want to copy the *format* (Font color, font size) or the *formula* (`=E5*$C5`)? Maybe you can edit your question with a screenshot showing what you want to do.

Comment: I want to copy the formula from one cell and paste it to another cell but I need that formula to automatically change to fit the correct cell . I can't screenshot it .

Comment: In that case you need to provide more details. What is the formula right now? What parts do you need to be changed? In what way? What should remain the same? It seems you already understand how the `$` operator works - so what functionality is missing? I suggest editing these details into your question.

Comment: Please continue the discussion on the main question please. I already suspected he wants `formula` not `format`, though.

Comment: =D5*$C5+D6*$C6+D7*$C7+D8*$C8+D9*$C9+D10*$C10+D11*$C11+D12*$C12+D13*$C13+D14*$C14+D15*$C15+D16*$C16+D17*$C17+D18*$C18+D19*$C19 this is the formula I want to change the "D" column to the appropriate columns.

Comment: Can you not drag the formula to the appropriate column? I'm confused as to what the appropriate column means. What exactly are you trying to do?